# Microsoft cognitive speech recognition in C#: StopMicAndRecognition does not stop the mic and keeps listening

Tags: speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

Sorry for long question and the bad English.

I have a problem using Bing Speech SDK in windows. I need to implement speech recognition in my c# application in windows.

In my application, I start the recognition, then stop it, produce a response, say it using a TTS,  then start listening again.

I can use the library included in the Microsoft Cognitive SDK, called Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition

There are two functions in the library:
StartMicAndRecognition() starts the recognition.
EndMicAndRecognition() stops the recognition.

The problem is:

EndMicAndRecognition() does not stop the mic from recording and sending the data to the server. So when I start the mic again, it returns words that have been said before the start function is called.

How can I stop the mic from recording?
Where can I find the source code to this library? (The binary files are included in the SDK and not the source code).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to release the micClient with the Dispose method.
I use this procedure in my project and it never showed the error you encounter.

Hope it can help.